# PHP : How to skip uploading a file if no file selected

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this PHP script that uploads contents of a form into a database along with an image. Now, I want to make it upload everything when it's selected (works) and skip the upload image part and upload everything but the image if it's not.

Below is a part that uploads the image on a server.

```
$time = time();
$uploader = $_SESSION['username'];
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $uploader . $time. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["addpost-btn"])){

$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
//the rest is a database insert that works
```

When I try to insert the form contents without the image it returns:

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\vinhub\inc\addpost.inc.php on line 14
>
> File is not an image.Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Line 14 being the $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

I assume it's because it requires the file to be selected but how do I bypass it and proceed with the insert without the image?

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try check isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])

```
<?php

$time = time();
$uploader = $_SESSION['username'];
$target_dir = "../uploads/";

if (isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . $uploader . $time . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (isset($_POST["addpost-btn"])) {

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
// Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
        //the rest is a database insert that works
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Now I need to figure out how to do the same for database insertion, as I have $photo = $target_file which inserts the "../uploads/$uploader.$time" either way. Would the same if statement work here? Let's say:
if (isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])){
  $photo = $target_file;
 } elseif(!isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
  $photo = ' ';}

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `getimagesize()` part of code. It just send you the warning if there is no image file. That warning will not interrupt code running.

But here's possible issue with this:

```
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
//the rest is a database insert that works
```

There is no closing `}` before the `//the rest is a database insert that works`

That means that database insertion will only goes if `$uploadOk == 1`.

So if you want to make database insertion anyway (either file was uploaded or not), then you need to fix this code to:

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
} //added brace

//database insertion here
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right that the code I pasted didn't have one } but it was just a copy-pasting mistake and the original code does indeed have it :)

Answer (score 0):

While Andrea's solution worked great, I still needed to insert a correct path into a database. The path was specified in `$target_file` hence initial `$photo = $target_file`. This inserted the path no matter if the file was uploaded or not.

My solution to it was:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToupload']['tmp_name'])) {
    $photo = $target_file;
 } else {
    $photo = '';
 }
```

Which checks is the file was actually uploaded and acts accordingly.
Thanks to everyone for help!